# validation messages are always shown

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i'm a student and have been stuck on this for a day now.
I have a form for personal information, everything is required to fill in and i need to show messages if its not filled in.

The problem is that the messages are shown the moment the page is loaded. How do i make it so that the messages are shown after i pressed the submit button?

```
<input asp-for="Naam" />

<label asp-for="Voornaam"></label>

<input asp-for="Voornaam" />

<label asp-for="Adress"></label>

<input asp-for="Adress" />

<label asp-for="Postcode"></label>

<input asp-for="Postcode" />

<label asp-for="Gemeente"></label>

<input asp-for="Gemeente" />

<label asp-for="Email"></label>

<input asp-for="Email" />

<label asp-for="Telefoon"></label>

<input asp-for="Telefoon" />

<input type="submit" value="Doorsturen" />
<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
```

this is in a .cshtml view page in mvc .net 5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing the model state just before returning the view in controller like this

```
 ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so stupid i coudnt find it.